# New df in R pulling from large existing df

Tags: r

In R, am trying to take this df I have called "gorilla" and create four new dfs by column identifiers. The "gorilla" spreadsheet has a column called "order", and this column has values that are either 1, 2, 3, and 4. I want to create a new df with "1" values only, and another one with "2" values only, etc. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```r
list2env(setNames(split(gorilla, gorilla$order), paste0("gorilla", 1:4)), 
         envir = globalenv())
```

Then you will have the 4 data frames in your workspace, called `gorilla1`, `gorilla2`, `gorilla3` and `gorilla4`

For example, if we have this dataset:

```r
set.seed(100)

gorilla <- data.frame(data = rnorm(10), order = sample(4, 10, TRUE))

gorilla
#>           data order
#> 1  -0.50219235     3
#> 2   0.13153117     4
#> 3  -0.07891709     2
#> 4   0.88678481     1
#> 5   0.11697127     4
#> 6   0.31863009     3
#> 7  -0.58179068     3
#> 8   0.71453271     4
#> 9  -0.82525943     2
#> 10 -0.35986213     1
```

We can do:

```r
list2env(setNames(split(gorilla, gorilla$order), paste0("gorilla", 1:4)),
         envir = globalenv())
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

And now we can see we have these objects available:

```r
gorilla1
#>          data order
#> 4   0.8867848     1
#> 10 -0.3598621     1
gorilla2
#>          data order
#> 3 -0.07891709     2
#> 9 -0.82525943     2
gorilla3
#>         data order
#> 1 -0.5021924     3
#> 6  0.3186301     3
#> 7 -0.5817907     3
gorilla4
#>        data order
#> 2 0.1315312     4
#> 5 0.1169713     4
#> 8 0.7145327     4
```

Note though that it is probably best in most circumstances to keep the data frames in a list:

```
gorillas <- split(gorilla, gorilla$order)
```

That way, you can just access `gorillas[[1]]` , `gorillas[[2]]` etc

Comment: This is all super helpful! I just looked at my gorilla df and realized the values in my "Order" column are not numbers -- for example, this is one of my column "Order" values: "HH-LH-HL-LL". Is there a way to make this code work for non numerical values in the column of interest for which I wish to segregate this df?

Answer (score 0):

An optioin with `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
gorillas <- gorilla %>%
               group_split(order)
```